# Cordova web app - how to navigate to the webapp without losing cordova.js and your plugins

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Am trying to convert our existing hybrid native/webapp to one based on Cordova.

I need to write and include plugins, and also there needs to be communication between the javascript in our web app and the cordova/native side of things, so I think a fairly standard cordova webapp. All the UI is in the WebView.

The problem I've got is that before we navigate to the app by changing window.location to the relevant url, all seems OK- I can make a call from the local app's index.js into the API we have exposed in one of our plugins..  So if I inspect the WebView, it looks fairly simple...

[image]

But once our app navigates, all that gets replaced with our web app, losing the JS side of the Cordova app.

I'm sure this must be a newb problem but I've been searching for a solution all morning.

Should I be using the inAppBrowser for this usecase? Am I wrong in believing that a web app in the inAppBrowser is restricted from calling functions that we expose in our cordova app?

Just an edit to add...   one thing I've seen mentioned is the requirement to include cordova.js and the plugin js code manually with your web app, so that it doesn't get lost when the page changes..

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-a-hosted-app/

"For the web site to run plugin code, cordova.js and the JavaScript plugin code need to be copied from the CordovaHostedApp-Client project to the CordovaHostedWeb project."

Is that right? I'm surprised I couldn't see this documented on the Cordova site, as I would have thought this would be a typical use-case for a serious production web app.

Comment: Are you navigating to an external web site or to a page within the Cordova app (and local to the device)?

Comment: external, for example  window.location = "http://www.mycorp.com/myfunkywebapp/index.html"

Comment: Have found this plugin which seems to promise what is needed. https://github.com/TruckMovers/cordova-plugin-remote-injection   Surprised that such a typical use-case needs to rely on a plugin that isn't part of the Cordova core

Comment: So there's a reason why this isn't considered "core" or typical functionality: it's a huge security risk and leads to a poor user experience in the case of no/flaky network connectivity. If you need live code updating, you can accomplish that using other methods (safer & better for the user experience), like Microsoft's code push option. I always counsel _against_ hybrid apps essentially wrapping external sites, and instead push to get that code local to the device.